# Is there a way to have Selenium in Python check a download window for content?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

I have a Python code use the Selenium Chrome driver to click multiple  tags in a list.

Each  opens a new window where a file is downloaded instantly, and that is all good; however, some of these new windows will have two files as options to download, so no file is downloaded until the next  tag is clicked.

The problem I have is that I can't let Selenium know how to "check" if it should just close the window since the download was automatic, or if it should do another click to begin the download.

I tried to do a find_elements_by_(all possible methods) to have the driver check if there are any download links, but if the download is automatic, the driver just keeps running. It doesn't turn an error or anything, but it just runs perpetually. If I close the actual download window, it THEN shows a result.

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe', options=options)

#options are set for Chrome to download a PDF file without viewing it first.

main_window = browser.window_handles[0]

#this is the initial click to open the download window 
browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('selector path').click()

#this is to have the driver activate the new window

pops = browser.window_handles[1]
browser.switch_to.window(pops)

#attempt to find the <a> tag with the download item
if browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('selector path') != []:
   time.sleep(1)
   browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('selector path').click()
   browser.close()
   browser.switch_to.window(main_window)
   #this works fine when there are tags in the window. No problems
else:
   time.sleep(1)
   browser.close()
   browser.switch_to.window(main_window)
   #code can't get to the "else" because the driver gets stuck checking for the selector perpetually.
```

What I expect is Selenium to check if the window has content, if not, delay for a second and close the window. If there IS content, click the link to download; however, the driver just searches for the selector perpetually.

EDIT: Forgot to mention the window that starts the download automatically doesn't have any content aside html, script, and head tags.

Even when I try to run a find_element_by_tag, Selenium doesn't actually find the content.

Comment: Do you have any `implicit wait` statements in you code? And make sure to update the `browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('selector path').click()` to `find_element_by_css` as `find_elements_by_css` will return an element list not an element.

Comment: I have a wait function that times out the code to wait for a page to load (didn't realized Selenium had this built into the library). Either way, the code keeps running in the new window with the download without doing anything. It's like Selenium is looking for the elements, but it's not that it's not finding them; it's just looking for them forever. I don't even get an error if the element is not there.